# Tracking Amazon associate analytics

Tags: amazon

I was pleasantly surprised to get about $60 from my Amazon account last week, but I couldn't find anywhere to understand how this amount was calculated.

Is there anyway to get good analytics on my Amazon associate account?
I'd like to know Which items have I earned money on and when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the [Amazon Associate login page](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/)
2. Login into the site with your Amazon account
3. The sidebar on the right displays your Earning summary. Select a date range, e.g. Quarter to Date, then [click of view full reports](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html?preSelectedPeriod=QuarterToDate)
4. You can choose among different report types to detect which items have been purchased and your commission.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed the reports tab. There are too many menus on the page.